# Vigenère cipher: How to make it so that the encrypted message appears in a print function?

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.6, vigenere

I'm a beginner in coding and in Python too. Right now I'm working on a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).

I've gotten far enough to encrypt the message using a key. I added comments on each section of code for reference. Here is my code. My question is below the code.

```
# Ask user for message
print('type a message.')
message = input()

# print a white line for neatness
print()

# ask user for a key
print('give your key')
key = input()

# create a range with the length of the message
ran = range(len(message))

# Iterate though the range and therefor show all the letters
for i in ran:
    # get current letters for this iteration
    currentLetter = message[i]
    currentKeyLetter = key[i % len(key)]

    # Get corresponding numbers
    numberLetter = ord(currentLetter)
    numberKeyLetter = ord(currentKeyLetter)

    # Add two letters
    sumTwoLetters = numberLetter + numberKeyLetter

    # Get the number of the encrypted letter
    newNumberLetter = sumTwoLetters % 128
    # Get the encrypted number based on number
    newLetter = chr(newNumberLetter)

    # print out the result
    printText = currentLetter + "(" + str(numberLetter) + ") + "
    printText += currentKeyLetter + "(" + str(numberKeyLetter) + ") = "
    printText += newLetter + "(" + str(newNumberLetter) + ")"
    print(printText)
```

The code asks for the user's input for the message and key. The `ran` variable creates a range with the length of the message.

After that, the `for` loop encrypts the message with the key using `ord` and `chr`

The encrypted letter is stored in the variable `newLetter`
the user can see what the program has done with `printText`

However, my question is: How can I make the encrypted text appear on a single string. I tried to do it in a loop. I failed miserably (so much so that I don't want to show it)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make the encrypted message appear in a single line of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can gather the results in a `list` and then `join()` them all into a single string at the end after the `for` loop. See the comments for the changes.

```
...
results = []  # ADDED.

# Iterate though the range and therefor show all the letters
for i in ran:
    # get current letters for this iteration
    currentLetter = message[i]
    currentKeyLetter = key[i % len(key)]

    # Get corresponding numbers
    numberLetter = ord(currentLetter)
    numberKeyLetter = ord(currentKeyLetter)

    # Add two letters
    sumTwoLetters = numberLetter + numberKeyLetter

    # Get the number of the encrypted letter
    newNumberLetter = sumTwoLetters % 128
    # Get the encrypted number based on number
    newLetter = chr(newNumberLetter)

    # print out the result
    printText = currentLetter + "(" + str(numberLetter) + ") + "
    printText += currentKeyLetter + "(" + str(numberKeyLetter) + ") = "
    printText += newLetter + "(" + str(newNumberLetter) + ")"
    results.append(printText)  # PUT IN results LIST INSTEAD OF PRINTING.

print(''.join(results))  # ADDED.
```

Comment: Thank you. I will play around with that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy ways. Either (1) build the string inside the loop and print it outside the loop, or (2) print each character as you move through the loop but without newlines, plus one newline after the loop.

Try one of those approaches and if you need more help, add a comment. You'll learn more by trying it yourself!

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. I will keep you posted.